# How to disable key speaking of keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I have enabled by mistake (I don't know how) a functionality that speaks every key that I press on keyboard. I don't know where I can disable that.

In accessibility, everything are disabled, voiceOver disabled,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Mac, click Apple menu > System Preferences > Accessibility > Spoken Content > Uncheck the “Speak typing feedback” checkbox. Also uncheck any of the other check boxes in the right pane (see screenshot) that are checked.

[image]

More details [here](https://support.apple.com/en-bn/guide/mac-help/mh27448/mac).